# how to get rand same array in php

Tags: php, arrays

what i want to do is something like memory game, but I keep cannot get the same number with the out put

```
$numbers = range(1, 15);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $key){
echo $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
break;  
}
```

now the out put will be something like this

```
4 2 3 3

1 5 3 6

2 3 4 5

10 9 8 10
```

but how to I do it as rand array and with same 2 array number, which is i can match the number.

what i want in out put is

```
2 3 1 4

3 4 2 1

5 6 9 7

7 9 6 5
```

so like this i can get the match in 2 same number

any idea how to do it?

thanks

Comment: can you provide me some code? i have no idea how to do this, actually the flow is same like memory game, its must can match

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do an array with couple values

```
// Generate array with values from 1 to 8
$arNumbers = range(1, 8); 
// Duplicate the array so get copy of each number
$arNumbers = array_merge($arNumbers, $arNumbers);

// Shuffle the array
shuffle($arNumbers);

// And now display them
foreach($arNumbers as $nNumber)
{
     // Do some business
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hi Mirko, I tested your code, its same result with what I did. anyway, thanks for kindly reply :)

Comment: :) I am not sure, what are you looking to achieve then

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing and vague. I extrapolate that you want to shuffle and display an array of numbers, two of each, in random order. To do that:

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 5);
$numbers = array_merge($numbers, $numbers);
shuffle($numbers);
echo implode(' ', $numbers);
```

This outputs, for instance, `3 5 1 5 1 2 3 4 2 4`.

The `array_rand()` call in the `foreach` in your code makes absolutely no sense. If the above isn't what you wanted, please revise your question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is a simple way.

```
$numbers=range(1, 15);
```

//Get 4 unique random keys from $numbers array.

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($numbers, 4);
```

//print out the random numbers using the
//random keys.

```
foreach ($rand_keys as $k=>$i) {

    echo $numbers[$i]."  ";
}
```

Hope this will helps you...

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you can achieve what you want to do with the following:

```
// make sure these are even numbers
$rows = 4;
$cols = 4;

$set = range(1, ($rows * $cols) / 2);
$numbers = array_merge($set, $set);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach (array_chunk($numbers, $cols) as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $col) {
        printf('%-5d', $col);
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
3    7    2    1    
4    6    8    5    
6    3    8    4    
2    5    7    1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do something like:

```
$numbers = range(1, 15);
shuffle($numbers);
$used_numbers = array();
foreach($numbers as $key){
  $this_number = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
  $used_numbers[] = $this_number;
  echo $this_number;
  break;  
}
$_SESSION['numbers'] = $used_numbers;
```

Then you can use the $_SESSION to access the numbers on another page (after reload perhaps), or use the same $used_numbers array to access them.

If you try:

```
$numbers = range(1, 15);
shuffle($numbers);
$used_numbers = array();
foreach($numbers as $key){
  $this_number = $numbers[array_rand($numbers)];
  $used_numbers[] = $this_number;
  echo $this_number;
  break;  
}
echo '<br />';
foreach($used_numbers AS $number) {
  echo $number;
}
```

You will see it returns the same number.

Comment: hi david, I tested your code, it's still the same, the echo rand number which is I cannot match it, but thanks for kindly reply :)

Comment: Try looping through $used_numbers afterwards and seeing if they come out the same ... - see my updated answer

Comment: thanks, david, your code was working to get the 2 same number, but how to I only show in time which is the number able to match?

Comment: sorry wrong grammer, what i mean now your number echo twice, so its display out 2 same number, but how to i show it in once instead of twice? and the number must be can match each other

Comment: You remove the second loop, I added it to demonstrate the numbers were the same. The numbers (that are shown) are stored in the $used_numbers variable, so you can use that as you wish.

Comment: ya, i know what you mean, but what i want is the first loop number can match the number inside the first loop as well, its something like memory game, you need to choose same image then only can match